# How to return module setup_version in Magento 2 controller?

Tags: magento2

I have a magento extension and I want to display setup_version in one of the controllers.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="My_Module" setup_version="0.0.3"/>
</config>
```

And inside controller:

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class Version extends AbstractIndex
{
    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $storeConfig;

    public function __construct(ScopeConfigInterface $storeConfig)
    {
        $this->storeConfig = $storeConfig;

    }

   public function execute() {
      // just prints the version
      echo (string)$this->storeConfig->getValue('modules/My_Module/setup_version');
   }
}
```

But obviously I do get an error:

Error: Call to a member function get() on null in /home/alexandru/magento24/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:109

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
namespace Module\Name\Model\Data;
use Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadataInterface;
class NameFile
{
    protected $productMetadata;
    public function __construct(
        ProductMetadataInterface $productMetadata
    ) {
        $this->productMetadata = $productMetadata;
    }
    public function getVersion()
    {
        $magentoVersion = $this->productMetadata->getVersion();
        return $magentoVersion;
    }
}
```